# How to start a calendar from monday with PHP

Tags: php, calendar

I have an event calendar that starts on Sunday. I must change it to start on Monday.

Part of my code:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
  $dagteller=$firstDayArray["wday"];
  $mDay=$firstDayArray["mday"];

  define("ADAY", (60*60*24));
  $mydate=getdate(date("U"));
  define("ADAY", (60*60*24));
  for ($count=0; $count < (6*7); $count++) {
      $dayArray = getdate($start);
      if (($count % 7) == 0) {
          if ($dayArray["mon"] != $month) {
              break;
          } else {
              echo ("</tr ><tr>\n");
          }
       }
   if ((!isset($_POST['month'])) || (!isset($_POST['year']))) {
       $nowArray = getdate();
       $month = $nowArray['mon'];
       $year = $nowArray['year'];
       $day = $nowArray['day'];
   } else {
       $month = $_POST['month'];
       $year = $_POST['year'];
   }
   // on my table 
   echo ("<td bgcolor=\"#DDDDDD\"><center>".$dayArray["mday"]."</center></td>\n");

   $start += ADAY;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where does it start on Sunday?

Comment: Provide good code, check my answer !!

Comment: Where is end bracket of `for` ?

Answer (score 1):

Read the PHP date manual for yourself: 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

The 'W' identifier will help you

Comment: I did change $mydate=getdate(date("U")); to $mydate=getdate(date("W"));. But nothing changed

Comment: only changed $dagteller=$firstDayArray["wday"] to $dagteller=$firstDayArray["wday"]-1 en that was solution